# Simple matching game on tkinter / Buttons and matrices binding

Tags: python, user-interface, matrix, tkinter

I am currently making a matching/memory game using tkinter.

The "Playing Screen" Is just a matrix of buttons. What I want to do is to give them a command that show the hidden image and disable the button, and if the next pressed button is a match, I need it to obviously stay like that.

The thing is that I have no Idea on how to do that, because I don't even know how to access to the button on the code. I mean, I create them, but now how can I enter every specific button for giving it an image (Which has to be a random one BTW because the game can't be the same all the time) and then giving it the command to stay or not?

This is probably a noob question, but I am just entering to the Matrices world, and tkinter.

Here's what I have made so far...

```
from tkinter import *


def VentanaPlay():
    matriz = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

    ventana = Tk()
    ventana.title('Ejemplo')
     
    longitud_i = len(matriz)
    longitud_j = len(matriz[0])

    def creaMatriz(i = 0, j = 0):
        if i == longitud_i and j == longitud_j:
            print('Listo')
        elif j < longitud_j:
            boton = Button(ventana, width = 10, height = 5)
            boton.grid(row = i, column = j)
            return creaMatriz(i, j + 1)
        else:
            return creaMatriz(i + 1, 0)

    creaMatriz()

    ventana.mainloop()
            
VentanaPlay()
```

So what I need is to know how to access the buttons of the matrix?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add button to list (or matrix)

for example

```
self.all_buttons = []

# ...

boton = Button( ... )
self.all_buttons.append( boton )
```

and then you can access button in position (x,y)

```
self.all_buttons[y*longitud_j + x]
```

for example

```
self.all_buttons[y*longitud_j + x].grid( ... )
```

---

**EDIT:**

BTW: you could use two `for` loops instead recursion to create buttons

---

**EDIT:**

Full example (I prefer object programming so I used `class`):

Click any button to change color to red, click again to change to green.

```
from tkinter import *

class VentanaPlay():

    def __init__(self):

        self.matriz = [
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        ]

        self.all_buttons = []

        self.ventana = Tk()
        self.ventana.title('Ejemplo')

        #self.long_x = len(self.matriz)

        #self.long_y = len(self.matriz[0])

        self.creaMatriz()

    def run(self):
        self.ventana.mainloop()


    def creaMatriz(self):
        for y, row in enumerate(self.matriz):
            buttons_row = []
            for x, element in enumerate(row):
                boton = Button(self.ventana, width=10, height=5, command=lambda a=x,b=y: self.onButtonPressed(a,b))
                boton.grid(row=y, column=x)
                buttons_row.append( boton )
            self.all_buttons.append( buttons_row )

    def onButtonPressed(self, x, y):
        print( "pressed: x=%s y=%s" % (x, y) )
        if self.all_buttons[y][x]['bg'] == 'red':
            self.all_buttons[y][x]['bg'] = 'green'
        else:
            self.all_buttons[y][x]['bg'] = 'red'

VentanaPlay().run()
```